# Once I create HibernateSessionFactory I cant close it and still connect to Database

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-envers

I'm using Hibernate (4.1.7) with db2 (1.3.166) an making use of Hibernate Envers

My problem is that is this, in my recreateDatabase() method I setup the database and create the hibernate and hibernate audit (Envers) tables, for some weird reason that I don't understand the Envers tables do not get created unless I configure a HibernateSessionFactory even though not created until after the call to SchemaExport().

The real problem is that any attempt to close the HibernateSessionFactory and recreate means it complains that it cannot see any of the hibernate tables.

The test demonstrate this.

*testRecreateHibernateTablesAndCreateSong()* creates a new database and then write a record to the database and works

*testRecreateHibernateTablesAndCreateSong2(*) creates a new database, then closes the hibernate session factory and then trys to create a new hibernate session factory and write a record to the database but fails with

```
Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Table "SONG" not found; SQL statement:
insert into Song (recNo, acoustidFingerprint, acoustidId, album, albumArtist, albumArtistSort, albumSort, amazonId, arranger, artist, artistSort, artists, barcode, bpm, catalogNo, comment, composer, composerSort, conductor, country, custom1, custom2, custom3, custom4, custom5, discNo, discSubtitle, discTotal, djmixer, duration, encoder, engineer, fbpm, filename, genre, grouping, isCompilation, isrc, keyOfSong, language, lastModified, lyricist, lyrics, matched, media, mixer, mood, musicbrainzArtistId, musicbrainzDiscId, musicbrainzOriginalReleaseId, musicbrainzRecordingId, musicbrainzReleaseArtistId, musicbrainzReleaseCountry, musicbrainzReleaseGroupId, musicbrainzReleaseId, musicbrainzReleaseStatus, musicbrainzReleaseTrackId, musicbrainzReleaseType, musicbrainzWorkId, musicipId, occasion, origFilename, originalAlbum, originalArtist, originalLyricist, originalYear, producer, quality, rating, recordLabel, releaseYear, remixer, script, subtitle, tags, tempo, title, titleSort, track, trackTotal, urlDiscogsArtistSite, urlDiscogsReleaseSite, urlLyricsSite, urlOfficialArtistSite, urlOfficialReleaseSite, urlWikipediaArtistSite, urlWikipediaReleaseSite, version) values (null, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?) [42102-166]
    at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:329)
    at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:169)
    at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:146)
    at org.h2.command.Parser.readTableOrView(Parser.java:4757)
    at org.h2.command.Parser.readTableOrView(Parser.java:4735)
    at org.h2.command.Parser.parseInsert(Parser.java:958)
    at org.h2.command.Parser.parsePrepared(Parser.java:375)
    at org.h2.command.Parser.parse(Parser.java:279)
    at org.h2.command.Parser.parse(Parser.java:251)
    at org.h2.command.Parser.prepareCommand(Parser.java:217)
    at org.h2.engine.Session.prepareLocal(Session.java:415)
    at org.h2.engine.Session.prepareCommand(Session.java:364)
    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcConnection.prepareCommand(JdbcConnection.java:1111)
    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcPreparedStatement.<init>(JdbcPreparedStatement.java:71)
    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcConnection.prepareStatement(JdbcConnection.java:266)
    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcConnection.prepareStatement(JdbcConnection.java:1041)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.stmt.GooGooStatementCache$1StmtAcquireTask.run(GooGooStatementCache.java:525)
    at com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$PoolThread.run(ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner.java:547)
```

The real world problem is as follows.

If I start application and create new database I can write to it no problem. But If I close  application and restart it is unable to now find the database tables (although it does seem able to connect)

**Update Ive just noticed that immediately after the closeFactory() method is called SQL is run that drops all the tables so that is why it cannot find the SONG table but why on earth would it do this !**

Full Self Contained Example Below:

```
package com.jthink.songlayer.hibernate;

import com.jthink.songlayer.*;
import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Environment;
import org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport;

import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

public class HibernateUtil
{
    private static AtomicInteger count = new AtomicInteger(0);
    private static SessionFactory factory;
    private static Logger logger;

    static
    {
        logger=Logger.getLogger("com.jthink.songlayer.hibernate.HibernateUtil");
    }

    private static void addEntitiesToConfig(Configuration config)
    {
        config.addAnnotatedClass(Song.class);
    }

    public static Configuration getInitializedConfiguration()
    {
        Configuration config = new Configuration();

        config.setProperty(Environment.DRIVER,"org.h2.Driver");
        config.setProperty(Environment.URL,"jdbc:h2:"+Db.DBFOLDER+"/"+Db.DBNAME+";FILE_LOCK=SOCKET;MVCC=TRUE;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE;CACHE_SIZE=50000");
        config.setProperty(Environment.DIALECT,"org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect");
        config.setProperty("hibernate.connection.username","jaikoz");
        config.setProperty("hibernate.connection.password","jaikoz");
        config.setProperty("hibernate.c3p0.numHelperThreads","10");
        config.setProperty("hibernate.c3p0.min_size","20");
        config.setProperty("hibernate.c3p0.max_size","100");
        config.setProperty("hibernate.c3p0.timeout","300");
        config.setProperty("hibernate.c3p0.maxStatementsPerConnection","50");
        config.setProperty("hibernate.c3p0.idle_test_period","3000");
        config.setProperty("hibernate.c3p0.acquireRetryAttempts","10");
        config.setProperty("hibernate.show_sql","true");
        //config.setProperty("org.hibernate.envers.audit_strategy", "org.hibernate.envers.strategy.ValidityAuditStrategy");
        config.setProperty("hibernate.format_sql","true");
        addEntitiesToConfig(config);
        return config;
    }

    public static Configuration getInitializedConfigurationAndRebuildAuditTables()
    {
        Configuration config = getInitializedConfiguration();
        config.setProperty(Environment.HBM2DDL_AUTO, "create-drop");
        return config;
    }

    public static Session getSession()
    {
        logger.finest("********** BEGIN SESSION" + count.incrementAndGet());
        if (factory == null || factory.isClosed())
        {
            createFactory();
        }
        Session hibernateSession = factory.openSession();
        return hibernateSession;
    }

    private static void createFactory()
    {
        logger.severe("----Initilizing Hibernate Session factory");
        Configuration config = HibernateUtil.getInitializedConfiguration();
        factory = config.buildSessionFactory();
    }

    public static void closeSession(Session session)
    {
        logger.finest("********** CLOSE SESSION" + count.decrementAndGet());
        if(session.isOpen())
        {
            session.close();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Close the factory, allows the database to be deleted
     */
    public static void closeFactory()
    {
        if(factory!=null && !factory.isClosed())
        {
            logger.severe("----Closing Hibernate Session factory");
            factory.close();
        }
    }

    /**
      Schema Export creates the normal table, then building SessionFactory using the special configuration creates
      the audit table.
     */
    public static void recreateDatabase()
    {
        Configuration config;
        config =
                HibernateUtil.getInitializedConfigurationAndRebuildAuditTables();
        new SchemaExport(config).create(false,true);
        factory = config.buildSessionFactory();
    }

    public static Session beginTransaction()
    {

        Session hibernateSession;
        hibernateSession = HibernateUtil.getSession();
        hibernateSession.beginTransaction();
        return hibernateSession;
    }

    public static void commitTransaction()
    {
        HibernateUtil.getSession()
                .getTransaction().commit();
    }

    public static void rollbackTransaction()
    {
        HibernateUtil.getSession()
                .getTransaction().rollback();
    }

    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        System.out.println("ReCreateStart");
        HibernateUtil.recreateDatabase();
        System.out.println("ReCreateEnd");

    }

}

mport com.jthink.songlayer.CoverImage;
import com.jthink.songlayer.Song;
import com.jthink.songlayer.hibernate.Db;
import com.jthink.songlayer.hibernate.HibernateUtil;
import junit.framework.TestCase;
import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.Transaction;
import org.hibernate.envers.AuditReader;
import org.hibernate.envers.AuditReaderFactory;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

/**
 *
 */
public class RecreateDatabaseTest extends TestCase
{
    public void testRecreateHibernateTablesAndCreateSong() throws Exception
    {
        Exception e = null;
        try
        {
            HibernateUtil.recreateDatabase();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ex.printStackTrace();
            e = ex;
        }
        assertNull(e);
        createSong();
    }

    public void testRecreateHibernateTablesAndCreateSong2()throws Exception
    {
        Exception e = null;
        try
        {
            HibernateUtil.recreateDatabase();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ex.printStackTrace();
            e = ex;
        }
        assertNull(e);

        HibernateUtil.closeFactory();

        createSong();
    }


    public void createSong() throws Exception
    {

        Exception ex = null;
        try
        {
            Session session = HibernateUtil.getSession();
            Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();
            Song song = new Song();
            song.setComposer("composer");
            session.save(song);
            tx.commit();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            ex = e;
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        assertNull(ex);
    }
}
```

Comment: Well it similar and also asked my me but this question is better as Ive nailed it down to a self-contained example, importantly shouldn't be marked as a duplicate because neither question has an answer.

Comment: Voting to reopen.  'This question ... already has an answer'?  It does not.